# Date type fields in Rails scaffold generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

If I generate new model, view and controller with rails scaffold generator I get next view for data type fields:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :deadline %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :deadline %>
</div>
```

In this case I view three fields on html-page (year, month and date) and get the next mongo document:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f6b0e4383b7e019ec000004"), "deadline(1i)" : "2012", "deadline(2i)" : "3", "deadline(3i)" : "22" }
```

But I want to have only one Date parameter.  How can I fix the view to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `date_select` helper do the split. If you want use another system you need create your own helper or write it directly in HTML.